# Cut folder path from URL via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to shorten my URL but sadly can't find anything that helps.

I divide my code in folders. Index is positioned at root just like my .htaccess.
The folders are named like the file extensions, so php, js, css [...]

I have a link like the following:

```
localhost/php/getBets.php
```

and want it to be

```
localhost/getBets/
```

I already have the part that cut's the .php extension at the end, so here is my full .htacces

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Hide Index
IndexIgnore *

# Forbid accessing certain sites
RedirectMatch 403 ^/.gitignore$
RedirectMatch 403 ^/.htaccess$
RewriteRule ^(?!index)(?!.*getBets).*\.(php|rb|py|txt|md|sql|inc)$ - [F,L,NC]

# Hide .php file ending in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Can someone maybe tell me how I could achieve this? :)
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your required url you can use below rule in root directory it is for rewriting,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ php/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks alot, works like a charme without any complications. <3

Answer (score 0):

Actualy Apache still does not have pathinfo($,PATHINFO_DIRNAME), function like has PHP.

Use %{REQUEST_URI}, like this example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /path-dirname/$1 [R=301,L]
```

may reset with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^.+/$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm not so sure what it does but when I add those lines and visit localhost/getBets the following URL gets visited "http://localhost/php/php/php/php/php/php/php/php/php/php/php/getBets"